# Optimal number of components in a beta mixture model

Tags: distributions, fitting, beta-distribution

This is a well-written blog on how we can fit a mixture of beta distributions to a dataset:

http://varianceexplained.org/r/mixture-models-baseball/

However, it would have been excellent to identify the optimal number of beta distributions one can fit a beta mixture model. I think one could figure this out using AIC/BIC but I am not sure how to do this or if there is already a package (preferably in R) that could do this. Any insights will be much appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks, Xi'an. I would appreciate how AIC/BIC applies to this particular problem.

Comment: There are constraints on AIC/BIC, for example, $N>100$ or $300$, that are severe enough that I wouldn't trust them for something as volatile as mixture models of beta distributions without checking first if all the conditions assumed actually apply to the data available.

Comment: BIC is a constistent criterion for estimating the number of component, AIC is not.